# How do I make a 2D object face the direction it is moving like drifting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I have two `GameObject`s: the car and the circle. The car follows the circle, and the circle is moving with the cursor. Currently, my car is following the circle from a distance. When the circle moves along the x-axis, I want to rotate the car like it's drifting.

Here is my car follow script:

```
public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform leader;
    public float followSharpness = 0.1f;

    Vector3 _followOffset;

    void Start()
    {
        // Cache the initial offset at time of load/spawn:
        _followOffset = transform.position - leader.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Apply that offset to get a target position.
        Vector3 targetPosition = leader.position + _followOffset;
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().rotation = 1.5f;

        // Keep our y position unchanged.
        //targetPosition.y = transform.position.y;

        // Smooth follow.    
        transform.position += (targetPosition - transform.position) * followSharpness;

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the whole point of drifting is that the car `doesn't face` in the `direction` it is `moving`?

Comment: @MickyD yes, but now the car doesn't rotate or something thats the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html):

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetPosition = leader.position + _followOffset;
    transform.position += (targetPosition - transform.position) * followSharpness;
    transform.LookAt(leader);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm not able to test that this code works right now, you'll have to try it out and see if it produces the desired result.

Comment: The car is already lookin the circle but car should rotate when the circle moves along the x-axis

Comment: @CemBerkeÇebi I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. `LookAt` should rotate the car as you desire. The only caveat is if the car and the circle are on different layers, in which case you can flatten the target position [as mentioned in this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/708842/view.html). `Vector3 flattenedLeaderPosition = new Vector3(leader.position.x, leader.position.y, 0);
 transform.LookAt(flattenedLeaderPosition);`

Comment: @Morinehtar what do you think `transform.LookAt` does?

Answer (score 0):

So from what you described, is you want to make the car always facing the cursor, so it is always "looking at" the cursor, here is how you can do it:

```
  Vector3 diff = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
     diff.Normalize();

     float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot_z - 90);
```

From [Answer: LookAt 2D Equivalent ?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html)